# PHP: Converting a String into a Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, laravel

I'm using `Laravel` and am attempting to write an artisan command that accepts an argument, $content, that then needs to be transposed to an array. For example:

```
    // An example of a value that is being passed in from the CLI and stored as $content
    $content = "['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']";
```

To clarify, `$content` is then being passed in as a function argument where it will be used to pull out the values from the actual result set. In other words, I'm receiving a response from an API and `$content` is the path to the values that I need to pull out of the response. For example, the hard coded version of the implementation looks like:

```
    $result = $report['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a'];
```

Now, `$result` contains the values that I need to process. However, I'm trying to make this dynamic so I don't repeat myself each time I add in a new data source to check for reports. Currently, I have 4 functions each with hard-coded paths to the desired result; the goal is to make it so that I can pass in an argument that contains the path to the desired values and refactor my code so I only have the one function which accepts the path to the values as an argument.

I hope that clarifies the end-goal and why I'm only referencing keys, not a value.

Anyway, back to the problem at hand. I've attempted different variations of the following:

```
    // Attempting to parse the string into an array
    $arr = explode("]", trim(str_replace("[","",$content), "]"));
```

This results in the following array:

```
    array (size=5)
      0 => string ''div'' (length=5)
      1 => string ''div'' (length=5)
      2 => string '0' (length=1)
      3 => string ''h2'' (length=4)
      4 => string ''a'' (length=3)
```

But, what I need is for the array to be formatted like the following:

```
    $array = ['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']
```

I attempted to do a `foreach($array as $element)` over `$arr` and do an `array_push` for each element, but that resulted in the same output as `$arr`.

How can I loop over the string and parse it into an array? Additionally, I need 0 to remain as an index, and not be type casted as a string. And, one last note, the value of `$content` will be completely different each time, so I need it to be quite flexible. The only part that will remain constant is the `[` and `]` will always encapsulate the keys.

I'd love to hear how others would solve this seemingly trivial problem (I've taken a few years off from programming and apparently have forgotten more than I care to admit ;)  ). I honestly thought that the str_replace and explode was going to provide me the result I was expecting...

But, after re-reading the php.net/explode doc, it's always going to cast each element as a string (thus overriding my 0 index), and I have no idea how to turn it into a nested array, instead of a simple, flat array.

I look forward to your advice and insight. Thanks.

EDIT:

Including the function that is making use of the arguments to help provide some greater clarity.

```
private function yql_check_website($url, $xpath, $content) {

    require_once('../vendor/OAuth.php');

    $statement = "select * from html where url='{$url}' and xpath='{$xpath}' ";

    $cc_key  = $this->key;
    $cc_secret = $this->secret;
    $url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    $args = array();
    $args["q"] = $statement;
    $args["format"] = "json";

    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);
    $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
    $url  = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
    $url .= "&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array($request->to_header());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
    $report = json_decode($rsp, true);

    // Dynamically inspect the $report object for the xpath content
    $result = $report . $content;

    unset($report);

    return $result;
}
```

So, $report contains the entire API response, but the only thing I need is the content that is provided in `$report['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']` (for this example, at least, the path is different for each report that I'm scraping). So, the reason I'm trying to convert the command line argument into an array is so that it can be used in the above code where `$content` is being called in order to navigate the API's response and return the values from that segment.

I hope that makes more sense. And, if there is a better way to achieve this end-goal, feel free to mention it. I may be taking the wrong approach...

Comment: `$array = ['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']` makes no sense. You have a bunch of keys but no value.

Comment: Do you want your $array to be like : `$array[0] = ['div'], $array[1] = ['div'], $array[2] = ['0']...`?

Comment: @meager, I've updated the question to clarify why I'm only referencing keys.

Comment: @DroBuddy, I din't get it, what your string looks like ?

Comment: @Akshat, not quite. It really is a path to an API response, so I need it to be formatted like `['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']` in order to get access to the values of `['a']`.

Comment: Is this your string `"$report['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']"` ?

Comment: @Sheikh, `['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']` is the string that I'm passing in as an argument. But, it's a string. I need it to be transposed into an array so that I can get access to the value of `['a']` from the API response.

Comment: @DroBuddy Will the position of 'a' be fixed? Can you please give a complete example specifying one input sample and the corresponding value/ result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a few methods for array access that provide "dot" access to arrays, including [array_get](http://laravel.com/api/function-array_get.html).  The method prototype looks like this:

```
function array_get(array $array, string $key, mixed $default = null)
```

So, in your case, you could write:

```
$results = array_get($report, "div.div.0.h2.a");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use preg_match_all here..

```
$content = "['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']";  
$expression = /\['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\']/;
$results = preg_match_all( $expression, $content, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
```

If you have to have the array be like what you're saying, you could do something like this (for starters - this is a little ugly though as it is...)

```
// array( ['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']
// visualizing...
// array( 'div' => array ( 'div' => 'array( "0" => array( "h2" => array( "a") ) ) ) );

function createDepth( $source, $currentKey, $nextDepth = null ) {
  if( !is_array( $nextDepth ) ) {
    $source[] = array( $currentKey => $nextDepth );
  } else {
    $nextKey = array_shift( $nextDepth );
    $source[] = createDepth( array( $currentKey => array() ), $nextKey, $nextDepth );
  }
  return source;
}
// Edit: doh, unset the first key..
unset( $matches[0] );

// Continue from here.
$currentKey = array_shift( $matches );
$holder = array();
$final = createDepth( $holder, $currentKey, $matches);
print_r( $final );
```

Note: All the above is untested...

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know how it works out. Thanks, Jonathon.

Comment: Well, that ended up returning `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ['div'] [1] => ['div'] [2] => ['a'] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => div [1] => div [2] => a ) )` but I think you're on to something here. I'll play around with `preg_match_all` and see if I can get the expression tweaked to provide the result I'm looking for. Thanks for pointing me in a solid direction. If I can get it work, I'll gladly accept this as the answer.

Comment: cool.  be sure to check out my edited answer... created a recursive function to build it.  It is untested though ( I built it in the editor and haven't really coded PHP in a little over a year heh)

Comment: Interesting... You're right that is a bit ugly, but it seems to make sense. I'll give it a go and see what I can make of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this  what you want ?

```
$str = "['div']['div'][0]['h2']['a']";
$str = preg_split('/]\[/', substr(str_replace("'", "", $str), 1, -1));
print_r($str);

Array (
    [0] => div 
    [1] => div 
    [2] => 0 
    [3] => h2
    [4] => a 
)
```

Comment: That's pretty close, but I need it to be multidimensional, so that it's like array( 'div' => array ( 'div' => 'array( "0" => array( "h2" => array( "a") ) ) . But, that gives me a good idea of how to go about things.